# How to share variable with sub-thread?

Tags: bash

I would like to run a bash script with a watchdog function launched in sub thread that will stop my program when a given variable reach a value. This variable is incremented in the main thread.

```
var=0

function watchdog()
{
   if [[ $var -ge 3 ]]; then
       echo "Error"
   fi 
}

{ watchdog;} &

# main program loop
((var++))
```

The problem in this code is that $var stays at 0. I also tried without {} around the watchdog call, same result.

Is my code style good ?

Comment: It's not a thread; it's a new process. It's an important distinction, because a thread is something that runs in the same address space as the process that creates it; a new process has its own, distinct address space.

Comment: Put simply, a process cannot alter a variable in its parent's address space. You need some sort of interprocess communication (sockets, the file system, etc) to pass information from the process that runs `watchdog` back to the parent.

Comment: Yes as @cdarke also points out with named pipes. Socket use seems to be a little heavy just for that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share variables between processes in `bash`, and it does not support multi-threading.  So you need a form of Inter-Process Communication.  One of the simplest is to use a *named pipe*, also known as a FIFO.

Here is and example:

```
pipe='/tmp/mypipe'
mkfifo "$pipe"

var=0

# Your definition is not strictly correct (although it will work)
watchdog()
{  
   # Note the loop
   while read var
   do  
       if (( var >= 3 ))      # a better way to do numeric comparisons
       then
          echo "Error $var"
       else
          echo "$var"
       fi 
       sleep 2                # to prevent CPU hogging
   done
}

watchdog < "$pipe" &          # No need for a group

# main program loop - ??? I see no loop

((var++))
echo "$var" > "$pipe"

((var++))
echo "$var" > "$pipe"

((var++))
echo "$var" > "$pipe"

echo "waiting"
wait   
rm "$pipe"
```

Example run:

```
$ bash gash.sh
1
waiting
2
Error 3
```

However I really don't see the point in using a separate process.  Why not just call a function to test the value after each change?

Comment: Thank you very much. The use of fifo could be good. But you're right, a simple function call should be a better way, especially when there is more than one variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you run your bashscript with a `.` before, it will be use the same environment and can change existing variable. Look at this:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
a=12
echo $a
$ a=1
$ echo $a
1
$ ./test.sh 
12
$ echo $a
1
$ . ./test.sh 
12
$ echo $a
12
```

After i run `. ./test.sh` the variable $a has been changed through the script.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your interesting answer, good to know. But, it is not really what I was looking for.